# Configuring WhatsApp callback URL using Next.js

Tags: node.js, next.js, whatsapp

I have some boilerplate code for a `get` req and a `post` request to my webhook endpoint using Next.js. My goal is to set this endpoint as the callback URL for my meta developer console whats app test number.

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import axios from 'axios'

const accessToken = process.env.TOKEN
const myToken = process.env.MY_TOKEN

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    const mode = req.query['hub.mode']
    const challenge = req.query['hub.challenge']
    const token = req.query['hub.verify_token']

    if (mode && token) {
      if (mode === 'subscribe' && token === myToken) {
        console.log('WEBHOOK_VERIFIED')
        return res.status(200).send(challenge)
      } else {
        return res.status(403)
      }
    }
  }
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const body = req.body
    console.log(JSON.stringify(body, null, 2))

    if (body.object) {
      if (
        body.entry &&
        body.entry[0].changes &&
        body.entry[0].changes[0].value.message &&
        body.entry[0].changes[0].value.message[0]
      ) {
        let phoneId = body.entry[0].changes[0].value.metadata.phone_number_id
        let from = body.entry[0].changes[0].value.messages[0].from
        let msg_body = body.entry[0].changes[0].value.messages[0].text.body

        console.log('BODY >>>', msg_body)

        axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: `https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/${phoneId}/messages`,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          },
          data: {
            messaging_product: 'whatsapp',
            to: from,
            text: {
              body: 'Hi From STS',
            },
          },
        })
        return res.status(200)
      }
    } else {
      return res.status(404)
    }
  }
}
```

I generate an ngrok URL proxied from 5001 and try to set that as the callback URL in the meta developer configuration tab for whats app. Upon clicking verify and save I see the following message: The callback URL or verify token couldn't be validated. Please verify the provided information or try again later. When checking my console I can confirm that the log `WEBHOOK_VERIFIED` is present.

I've seen others with this error but not a clear solution for my use case.